# Using JavaScript for scripting in C++ code

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using version 3.1.

On the internet I find various references to how JavaScript can be used in Cocos2d-x as a scripting language for rapid iteration. However, all Docs regarding this seem to be outdated, and there are only Lua samples in the Cocos2d-x test samples.

Has JavaScript usage been removed from Cocos2d-x entirely, and I now have to rely on Lua?

Otherwise, how do I bind C++ code to JS and how do I call JS code from C++?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D This question is not about the JS binding of Cocos2d. I'm talking about using JS as a scripting language from within a C++ application (e.g. to do pure gameplay code in JS and performance-sensitive code in C++), which seems to have been possible in the past, and is still possible using Lua (see libLua in the cocos2d-x build project). Unless I misunderstand something, what you're showing me looks like a pure JS-based workflow.

Comment: not exactly, -js is an extension project, you can mix and match c++ and js. Afaik js doesn't even work without -x

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It seems that you are right. How would I got about extending an existing Cocos2d-x project to enable me to run simple JavaScript scripts?